# SSIS Script component Transaction

Tags: transactions, ssis, script-component

I am trying to use script component as transformation for processing a non formatted flat file.

I can achieve everything, but i would like to fail the component as well as the parent component holding it. The target is a oleDB destination. When i redirect the rows it goes and writes the row. But if there is any error in the file it should rollback everything for the relevant file and go to the next file for processing.

Any insight how can i get that worked? I have tried manytimes but if the exception is handled with try catch block the component doesn't fail. Any even if it fails it doesn't go to the next file for processing.

Comment: can you post some of your scrip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found similar solution to the problem. Adding  sql tasks before to start transaction and checking with variables in precedence constraints i was able to commit or rollback the changes made to the Oledb Destination in my DFT.

Thanks